# How to Jasmine test value of Object.constructor and reduce repition in it statements - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I defined an object model in my AngularJS application... it looks like so:

```
.factory('Watermark', function () {

    // Constructor, with class name
    // Assumption: that backend gives us a topic or not!
    function Watermark(content, title, author, topic) {
        this.content = content;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        if(topic) {
            this.topic = topic;
        }
    }

    // Example Public method, assigned to prototype
    Watermark.prototype.getDocumentType = function () {
        return this.content;
    };

    return Watermark;
});
```

Now, I wish to test this using jasmine, I want to determine that when I create an new instance of an object its `constructor` has the value of fuction I used (in this case Watermark). My current test fails (see the xit) below...

```
describe('Service: Watermark', function () {

    // load the module / APP
    beforeEach(module('MyAppName'));

    var Watermark;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_Watermark_){
        Watermark = _Watermark_;

        setTimeout(function(done) {
            done();
        }, 1);

    }));

    it('should be defined', function () {
        expect(Watermark).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('when defining a watermark with content "Book"', function () {

        it('should be an instance of "Watermark"', function () {
            var waterMark = new Watermark('Book','When boyfriends aint so super','Mary Jane','Doomed Romance');

            expect(waterMark instanceof Watermark).toBeTruthy();
        });

        //THIS FAILS!!!
        xit('should have a constructor property "Watermark"', function () {
            var waterMark = new Watermark('Book','When boyfriends aint so super','Mary Jane','Doomed Romance');
            console.log(waterMark.constructor);
            expect(waterMark.constructor).contains('Watermark');
        });

        it('should contain a content property with value "book"', function () {
            var waterMark = new Watermark('Book','When boyfriends aint so super','Mary Jane','Doomed Romance');

            expect(waterMark).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
                content: 'Book'
            }));
        });

        it('should contain a title property with value "When boyfriends aint so super"', function () {
            var waterMark = new Watermark('Book','When boyfriends aint so super','Mary Jane','Doomed Romance');

            expect(waterMark).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
                title: 'When boyfriends aint so super'
            }));
        });

        it('should contain a author property with "Mary Jane"', function () {
            var waterMark = new Watermark('Book','When boyfriends aint so super','Mary Jane','Doomed Romance');

            expect(waterMark).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
                author: 'Mary Jane'
            }));
        });

        it('should contain a topic property with "Doomed Romance"', function () {
            var waterMark = new Watermark('Book','When boyfriends aint so super','Mary Jane','Doomed Romance');

            expect(waterMark).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
                topic: 'Doomed Romance'
            }));
        });
    });

    describe('when defining a watermark with content "journal"', function () {

        it('should not contain a topic property', function () {
            var waterMark = new Watermark('Journal','My pretty lousey life as SpiderMan', 'Peter Parker');

            expect(Object.keys(waterMark)).not.toContain('topic');
        });
    });
});
```

I get the error **TypeError: undefined is not a constructor** I am unsure what I am doing wrong here?

Also would it be possible to reduce the repitition of me declaring the new instance within the `it('....`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the `toContains()` matcher function (rather than `contains()`). That `undefined is not a constructor` error may be because the test browser can't find a definition for the `contains()` function--I can see how that would throw you off in this case.

To answer the second part of your question, you can avoid repeatedly defining `var waterMark` by declaring it once within the `describe` block, before all the tests, and then setting it within a `beforeEach()` function.